# how to get NSIncludesSubdomains work

Tags: ios

So I have a CDN URL ss0.bdstatic.com, which needs to be added in `Exception Domains` in ATS. However, this is a CDN network, so different cities may have different address like ss1.bdstatic.com, or others.

So I write `bdstatic.com` as the name, and set `NSIncludesSubdomains` to `YES`. However, this does not work, even `ss0.bdstatic.com` is break.

How to get `NSIncludesSubdomains` work correctly?

Comment: `ss0.bdstatic.com` is not the subdomain- `bdstatic.com` would be the subdomain surely. Try setting the actual name as `ss0.bdstatic.com`

Comment: ad I said already, I write bdstatic.com as the name, this does not work, even ss0.bdstatic.com is break

Comment: I see, seems like you can't actually guarantee the domain then so maybe you should just turn off ATS entirely,,,

Comment: @DanielGalasko I have did it as I have no choice, which is aweful